# Inbuild function to select indicies that are within a radial distance from the origin index

Tags: matlab

For an n-dimensional array, I'm looking for an inbuild function that does the following (given in the 3d case):

```
    for l = 1:size(dct, 1)
        for m = 1:size(dct, 2)
            for n = 1:size(dct, 3)
                if sqrt(l*l + m*m + n*n) > r
                    break
                end
                new(end+1) = dct(l,m,n);
            end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ndgrid` and logical indexing:

```
r = 5; % assume radius

% make some fake data
dctDim = [3 4 5];
dct = randn(dctDim);

% make indexes
[l, m, n] = ndgrid(1 : size(dct, 1), 1 : size(dct, 2), 1 : size(dct, 3));

% extract values from dct within r-radius of top-left of array
new = dct(l.^2 + m.^2 + n.^2 <= r^2);
```